# Dynamically finding a particular array index

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

I have a large multi-dimensional array with multiple occurrences of `#options` indexes. The following is a single array example:

```
FORM => Array
(
    [#attached] => Array
        (
            [library] => quiz/quiz-form-styling
        )

    [text_0] => Array
        (
            [#type] => markup
            [#markup] => 
Wherelese did Walter White work besides being a teacher?


        )

    [radio_1] => Array
        (
            [#type] => radios
            [#options] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  An elder Care home
                    [1] => [A car wash]
                    [2] =>  A beauty saloon
                    [3] =>  For Skylers old boss
                )

            [#correct] => testing_correct_for radio
        )

    [text_2] => Array
        (
            [#type] => markup
            [#markup] => 
        )
)
```

In the example above, the parent array of **#options** is *radio_1*. But that is not always the case as the arrays are dynamically generated. There is no way to know in advance what the parent index would be but there is always an *#options* index.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to find and retrieve the data in all occurrences of **#options**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest iterating the set of form elements and checking if an inner `#options` key exists. If so, you can add the options to your array of all options.

```
$all_options = [];
foreach ($form_elements as $name => $settings) {
    if (isset($settings['#options'])) {
        $all_options[$name] = $settings['#options'];
    }
}
```

I used the element name as key in the example code, because I thought it seemed like it would be convenient to know where the options came from, but you wouldn't have to do it that way. If you just wanted them all in one big list, you could merge them onto `$all_options` instead of appending them.

```
$all_options = array_merge($all_options, $settings['#options']);
```

This is assuming each of the values under FORM is an array representing one form element. If there is any nesting such that `#options` could appear at a deeper level, a recursive search could handle that, but if not, I think it's best to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like recursive function

Here is simple example for above case.

```
$alloptions = array();
function seach($searcharray){
    foreach($searcharray as $key=>$value){
       if($key == '#options'){
       $alloptions[] = $searcharray[$key];
       }else if(is_array($value)){
           seach($value);
       }
    }
}
```